# Looking to trace name of only witness via signature on Baptism Cert 1870 Dublin St Pauls

Tags: palaeography, baptism-records, ireland, witness

Child born = Elizabeth Gibson, 25th May 1870, parents Samuel Gibson, Rose McGauran, residence, 64 Arbour Hill (in Dublin not in script)

[image]

Witness = ??, could be Catherine ??? – Looking to trace name of witness?[image]

Source: St. Paul's, Dublin City, Dublin, Ireland,

https://registers.nli.ie/registers/vtls000633673#page/77/mode/1up

Comment: I'm looking at it on a phone screen, but I'd say it's **Catharine King**.

Answer (score 3):

agree - Catherine King

Just to clarify it's St. Paul's RC (i.e. Arran Quay), there was also a St. Paul's CofI nearby

The residence on the (civil) birth registration is different for some reason, maybe they moved between the birth and baptism (25th May - 3rd June) - appears to be 9 Usher street. The birth was at the lying in hospital, no firstname for the child in the record.

64 Arbour Hill and 9 Usher street are both shown as tenements in Thom's Directory street listings around that time.